# How to get list of apps installed by user in Facebook without Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK (javascript) in a ASP.NET C# application to retrieve the **list of apps installed by an user**.

When I tried retrieving list of apps installed by users in Facebook with the help of Graph API, I came across some links saying that there isn't a way to get that.

Is there any other options available to retrieve this information ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: No you can't. Privacy issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without the Graph API, you can´t get ANYTHING from Facebook. Even if you would parse data from Facebook somehow, it would count as "scraping", which is not allowed.

In order to get the list of Apps owned by a user, you have to authorize the user (without any special permission) and use the `/me/applications` endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/applications/developer

If you want to get the INSTALLED Apps of the user, that´s not possible at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Luschn !!

The option (/user/applications/developer) you have suggested just gets me only the Facebook apps that was created by the user/ the one which user is an administrator.

But, my requirement is to get the list of all apps which user already has in the account. Simply we say, I would like to get the apps presented in "Apps" section in Facebook.

Comment: There is no way of getting that. No really, there is not.

Comment: yup, that´s not possible at all, i will add that to my answer

Comment: you did write "owned by the user", so i thought it´s about...well, apps he is an admin/developer of, not just the apps he authorized ;)